# Odoo POS popup widget Text input not working

Tags: javascript, popup, odoo-9, odoo-10, point-of-sale

I have created a new payment method for card payment. when choosing this payment option, a popup will arise to get the card details from the user. here **i can't key in the details in the input fields. ( ctrl+v is working ).**

i tested the odoo base popup widgets like **TextInputPopupWidget** and **TextIAreaPopupWidget** both are not working and can't key in the values.

Any solutions.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keyboard are block at payment time in POS . So You need to override both

```
this.keyboard_handler = function(event){
var key = '';
            if (event.type === "keypress") {
                if($(".your popup div class").not('.oe_hidden').length){
                    return;
                }

              rest of code......
};

and 

this.keyboard_keydown_handler = function(event){
            if($(".your popup div class").not('.oe_hidden').length){
                return;
            }
     rest of code......
};

Thanks
```